# Query Value in data source range

Tags: axapta

I am getting a problem in query range value. and i am not getting the propriate values from the query. I am working in axapta 3.0.

I want to get such items which are not expired yet or have no expire date (means null date).

this.query().dataSourceName('dsTable').addRange(fieldnum(ItemTable,ExpireDate));
this.query().dataSourceName('dsTable').range(1).value(strfmt('(ExpireDate > %1) || (ExpireDate == %2 )', today(), DateNull() ) ;

I have use the expression in query value and it didnot work.

First i thing that it old version and not support it.

Anyother solution will be welcome.

Regards,
Kashif.

Comment: I think you are missing some round brackets in your query expression. See also "Expressions in query ranges" (http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges)

Comment: I had checked the brackets in query, but i looks fine. No syntax error. Anyway, the string paramenter in value method has the value like ( (ExpireDate > 01\01\2013) || (ExpireDate ==  ) ) , when seeing through the breakpoint.

Comment: this.query().dataSourceName('dsTable').range(1).value( QueryValue(strfmt(' (ExpireDate>%1) || (ExpireDate==%2) )', today(), Datenull() ))) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.value(strfmt('"",>%1', today()))`

Comment: Or even: `.value('"",d..')`

Comment: Thusind Tak Jan. Det gør meget godt :).  Kan jeg spørg hvad var mangler i min egen Query? Hilsener Kashif

Comment: Jan, `'%1..'` is equivalent to `'>=%1'`, not to `'>%1'`, so the result would be different.